# Why the thrown objects are not thrown forward?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to throw objects the same direction the camera is pointing to (forward), but it is behaving really weird.  Objects don't always get thrown forward, sometimes it gets thrown up or towards the player itself (backward). And I don't know why:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a snippet of `PickingUp` class:

```
public float throwForce = 1000f;
...
 private void PickUpObject(GameObject pickUpObj)
    {
        if (pickUpObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()) 
        {
            heldObj = pickUpObj; 
            heldObjRb = pickUpObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
            heldObjRb.isKinematic = true;
            heldObjRb.transform.parent = holdPos.transform; 
            heldObj.layer = LayerNumber;                              
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(heldObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), player.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
            reticle.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75f);
            reticle.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void DropObject()
    {
        //re-enable collision with player
       Physics.IgnoreCollision(heldObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), player.GetComponent<Collider>(), false);
       heldObj.layer = 0; //object assigned back to default layer
       heldObjRb.isKinematic = false;
       heldObj.transform.parent = null; //unparent object
       heldObj = null; //undefine game object
       reticle.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75f);
       reticle.enabled = true;
    }
 void ThrowObject()
    {
        //same as drop function, but add force to object before undefining it
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(heldObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), player.GetComponent<Collider>(), false);
        heldObj.layer = 0;
        heldObjRb.isKinematic = false;
        heldObj.transform.parent = null;
        Vector3 camerDirection = camera.transform.forward;
        heldObjRb.AddForce(camerDirection * throwForce);
      //  heldObjRb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None; 
        heldObj = null;
        reticle.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75f);
        reticle.enabled = true;
    }
```

All objects have Rigidbody and colliders attached to them. I get the same issue when dropping the objects too.

Comment: maybe `throwForce` is just too low? It is easier in that case to just set a fixed `velocity` instead `heldObjRb.velocity = camerDirection * throwVelocity;`

Comment: Try disabling object's collider altogether.

Comment: also good point by @HasnainShaukat maybe your object is hitting your player

Comment: ThrowForce is 1000f.

Comment: I think the objects are really hitting the player. But I don't know why and how to fix it. I need colliders in all my objects I just can't disable them.

Comment: Then use CollisonMatrix in Physics setting so that undesirable layers don't collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the [force mode as impulse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html) on the AddForce method. The default is acceleration which can often require unreasonable large numbers to get the desired effect.

```csharp
 heldObjRb.AddForce(camerDirection * throwForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

A lot of people pointed out that your issue might be collision between the pickupobject and the players collider. You're using a method that tells the physics engine to ignore the collisions that I'm not familiar with, but should be fine to use for your purpose.
I would suggest enabling the collision after a short time delay, so the object has enough time to escape the players collider. You can do so with an invoke.

```csharp
void ThrowObject()
{
  //same as drop function, but add force to object before undefining it
  heldObj.layer = 0;
  heldObjRb.isKinematic = false;
  heldObj.transform.parent = null;
  Vector3 camerDirection = camera.transform.forward;
  heldObjRb.AddForce(camerDirection * throwForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
  //  heldObjRb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None; 
  reticle.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75f);
  reticle.enabled = true;
  Invoke("ResetCollision", 0.5f);//can be adjusted
}

public void ResetCollision(){
  Physics.IgnoreCollision(heldObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), player.GetComponent<Collider>(), false);
  heldObj = null;
}
```